# evaluate JSON expression in child object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to evaluate json expression using [Josson](https://github.com/octomix/josson), but it gives invalid function error

```
String json ="{\"data\":{\"B\":\"calc(348+(96*$.SelectedPump.stg*$.ModelMaster.count))\"},\"SelectedPump\":{\"stg\":10,\"ab\":200},\"ModelMaster\":{\"count\":20}}";
        
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json.toString());
System.out.println(josson.getNode("data.eval(B)"));
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid function call eval() : Invalid function call calc() : Calc syntax error.
    at com.octomix.josson.FuncDispatcher.apply(FuncDispatcher.java:84)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:328)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:352)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:249)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathByExpression(JossonCore.java:211)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:147)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:142)
    at com.octomix.josson.Josson.getNode(Josson.java:279)
```

Comment: can you use `okhttp` `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible to reference values within `calc()` that reside at a different node/level. As soon as you include a `.` in the `calc` function, it fails

Answer (score 2):

The variables inside the math equation cannot contains special characters. You need to use substitution. The variable name can whatever you want without special characters and `.`. So, the statement of B become...

```
calc(348+(96*A*B), A:SelectedPump.stg, B:ModelMaster.count)
```

The function `eval()` in query `data.eval(B)` works on node `data`. So the original evaluation statement needs `$.` to re-start from the root to get the value. For this revised version `eval(data.B)`, `eval()` works on the root node with parameter `data.B`. And therefore, `$.` is not necessary.

```
String json =
    "{\n" +
    "    \"data\": {\n" +
    "        \"B\": \"calc(348+(96*A*B), A:SelectedPump.stg, B:ModelMaster.count)\"\n" +
    "    },\n" +
    "    \"SelectedPump\": {\n" +
    "        \"stg\": 10,\n" +
    "        \"ab\": 200\n" +
    "    },\n" +
    "    \"ModelMaster\": {\n" +
    "        \"count\": 20\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "}";
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json);
System.out.println(josson.getNode("eval(data.B)"));
// Output: 19548.0
```

Comment: Should be `A:$.SelectedPump.stg, B:$.ModelMaster.count` because they are not a child node of `data`. Also can you provide a source where you got this from? Couldn't find anything on the github readme

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks to remind me. I forgot to post the corresponding revised query after removing the `$.`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer That is described in the readme at tutorial point 55.

Comment: Took a bit to find it cause the search can't find that entry for whatever reason. `mXparser expression accepts single-step path only. To apply multi-steps path, function or filter, append arguments with syntax newVariable:path` is the explanation given in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by Raymond Choi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75095081/7109162)  would be the best solution.

---

Alright, I have found a possible solution to this using [Jossons](https://github.com/octomix/josson#fill-in) template engine.

```
String json = "{\"data\":{\"B\":\"calc(348+(96*{{SelectedPump->stg}}*{{ModelMaster->count}}))\"},\"SelectedPump\":{\"stg\":10,\"ab\":200},\"ModelMaster\":{\"count\":20}}";

Jossons jossons = Jossons.fromJsonString(json);
String output = jossons.fillInPlaceholder("{\"s\":\"{{data->B}}\"}");
output = jossons.fillInPlaceholder(output);
System.out.println(output);
System.out.println(Josson.fromJsonString(output).getNode("$.eval(s)"));
```

It is necessary to adjust the JSON string to use placeholder to access the values from a different/nested node. We also have to create a new JSON string with a template that is filled in. Also also, it does sadly not recursively replace the placeholder, making it necessary to call `jossons.fillInPlaceholder()` two times. The first time it fetches the calculated formula and the second time it replaces the placeholder that are now present in the formula.

The output is:

```
output -> {"s":"calc(348+(96*10*20))"}
Josson.fromJsonString(output).getNode("$.eval(s)") -> 19548.0
```

---

The proposed code in the question fails, because Josson is not able to resolve nested/different node values. Pretty much as soon as we have a `.` present in the `calc()` formula, the syntax check fails. It is however possible to access nodes at the same level. So a JSON like this:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "B" : "calc(348+(96*SelectedPumpStg*ModelMasterCount))",
    "SelectedPumpStg" : 10,
    "ModelMasterCount" : 20
  }
}
```

can be evaluated by:

```
String json = "{\"data\":{\"B\":\"calc(348+(96*SelectedPumpStg*ModelMasterCount))\",\"SelectedPumpStg\":10,\"ModelMasterCount\":20}}";
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json.toString());
System.out.println(josson.getNode("data.eval(B)"));
```

resulting in the same: `19548.0`.

Either way, the input JSON has to be adjusted to work with `Josson`